# ADFS 2.0 url in trusted site on extranet or internet?

Tags: internet-explorer, adfs

ASP.NET application is using ADFS 2.0 for authentication.

We have added adfs url in trusted site for intranet web site application.

Do we need to add adfs url to trusted site for public / extranet/ internet production website as well on client machine?

Comment: Why do you think ADFS url needs to be added in "trusted sites" at all?

Comment: @NewDev, for our intranet test site we added that site to trusted site, but again it does not matter as i can not access intranet site on internet. hence i am not sure how it will behave for production site. Do you have any idea about what will be the behavior and how it can impact adfs login or user session?